# Share $scope between DOM elements with same ng-controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm stuck with something (I've been reading similar questions but none of them get me to the solution).
I  have 2 DOM elements (let's say 2 div's) with different id's but the same ng-controller (this is for basic example, in my real app I have 2 differente pages but works the same).

```
<div id="layer1" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedType" ng-options="type.label for type in ptype track by type.value" ng-change="changeType(selectedType.value)"></select>
</div>
<div id="layer2" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedType" ng-options="type.label for type in ptype track by type.value" ng-change="changeType(selectedType.value)"></select>
</div>
```

And in JS

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', [])
.factory('selectedType', function(){
  return{}
})
.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.ptype = [
  {
      value: 1,
      label:'Kg'
  },
  {
      value: 2,
      label:'Pza'
  }];
  selectedType = $scope.ptype[0];
  $scope.changeType = function(value){
    if(value==1){selectedType = $scope.ptype[0];}
    else{selectedType=$scope.ptype[1];}
  };
}])
```

As you can see I have the options for the SELECT and the ng-model, what I need is when change the selected value in any SELECT (doesn't matter which DIV) the other gets updated too.

Here a Plunker with code [SEE HERE](https://plnkr.co/edit/7wwjmiz3tmhV4BXaGwCM?p=preview).
Thanks!

Comment: You aren't realizing that each `ng-controller` is a new isolated instance of `AppCtrl`. Use a service to share data across different controllers or keep both in same instance or less desirable approach is  move `$scope.ptype` declaration to a parent controller that encapsulates both instances which would inherit from parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Shared service like your attempt:

you are in the good way but you just forgot that :

1 - you use the scope in ng-model,

2 - to have 2 way data binding for factory,

- bind the factory itself to a scope,
- and use an item inside the factory not the factory itself (eg: data).

code:

```
.factory('selectedType', function(){
  return {
    data: {}  // <---- We use 'data' here for example
  }  
})
```

and in the controller now:

```
.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', 'selectedType',function($scope, selectedType) {
    $scope.selectedType = selectedType; // <-- Not the selectedType.data (Important)
    /* but the factory object */
    $scope.ptype = [
      {
        value: 1,
        label:'Kg'
      },
      {
        value: 2,
        label:'Pza'
      }];
    $scope.selectedType.data = $scope.ptype[0];
})
```

Now we dont need the ng-change at all:

```
<div id="layer1" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedType" ng-options="type.label for type in ptype track by type.value"></select>
</div>
<div id="layer2" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedType" ng-options="type.label for type in ptype track by type.value"></select>
</div>
```

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/5qg45F?p=preview

NB: Instead of using shared service, you can also use $rootScope or $scope.$parent for that.

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm!... I felt I was close to solution but got lost in the way hehehe. Greetings!